# $ionicPopup: e.preventDefault() gets ignored

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, firebase, ionic-popup

I'm using the following code for some validation stuff using both $ionicPopup and Firebase:

```
onTap: function(e) {
    firebase.auth().applyActionCode($scope.data.emailcnfrm)
        .then(function() {
            return $scope.data.emailcnfrm;
        },
        function(error) {   
            alert("wrong code");
            e.preventDefault();
        });
}
```

But In the case of error, and after I get the "wrong code" alert, the popup gets closed, as `e.preventDefault();` has been ignored.

So what's exactly wrong in my code? and how can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I solved the problem by using my own trick:

-outside Async:

```
         $scope.myPopup = $ionicPopup.show({

             scope: $scope, buttons: [

             { text: 'Cancel' },

             {                  
                 text: '<b>Done</b>',

                 type: 'button-positive',

                 onTap: function(e)
                 {

                 // always keep the popup open, because we'll decide when to close it later
                 e.preventDefault();

                 $AsyncCallback();
                 }
             }
             ]
         });

$scope.myPopup.then(function(){},
                             function(error)
                             {
                                 $ionicPopup.alert({

                                 title: 'Internal error!',

                                 template: error
                                 });
                             });
```

-inside async:

```
$scope.myPopup.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

Your call to `firebase.auth().applyActionCode` is asynchronous, and `e.preventDefault` will be called asynchronously in the error callback. This happens *after* the user has already invoked `onTap`, thus `e.preventDefault` won't have any effect.

### Edit (a proposed fix)

To fix it, you could separate the async logic from the `onTap` method:

```
var myPopup = $ionicPopup.show({
  onTap: function(e) {
    // always keep the popup open, because we'll decide when to close it later
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});

myPopup.then(function(res) {
  firebase.auth().applyActionCode($scope.data.emailcnfrm)
  .then(function() {
    // if successful, imperatively close the popup
    myPopup.close();
  }, function(err) {
    // log the error, or something
  });
});
```

Comment: I tried what you've recommended but it didn't work as expected: `myPopup.then` gets executed after myPopup gets closed.